# k-th smallest number of standard normal distribution

Tags: probability

There are $n$ random variables obey the standard normal distribution $N(0 ,1)$.

What is the expectation of the k-th smallest number?

### My attempt

I tried to use conditional probability to solve the problem, but the situation of $n=4$ is too complex to handle.

#### for n = 2

$$p_1(x) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} }{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

$$p_2(x) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} }{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1\right)$$

$E_1 = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}, E_2 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}$

#### for n = 3

$$p_1(x) = \frac{3 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} }{4 \sqrt{2 \pi }}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2$$

$$p_2(x) = -\frac{3 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} }{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}\left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2-1\right)$$

$$p_3(x) = \frac{3 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} }{4 \sqrt{2 \pi }}\left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1\right)^2$$

$E_1 = -\dfrac{3}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}, E_2 = 0, E_3 = \dfrac{3}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}$

Is there any good way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Can you find the distribution of the largest number? Let's call the random variables $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$, and the maximum out of them is $x_{max}$.  The probability that $x_{max}$ is less than some value $a$ is given by $\prod_{i=0}^n p(x_i < a)$, where $p(x_i < a)$ is the probability that random variable $x_i$ takes a value less than $a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20kth%20order,non%2Dparametric%20statistics%20and%20inference.) of the $k$-th smallest number among $n$ i.i.d standard normal random variables is given by
$$
f_{X_{(k)}}(x) = \frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!} \phi(x) \left[\Phi(x)\right]^{k-1}
\left[1-\Phi(x)\right]^{n-k},$$
where $\phi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$ are PDF and CDF of standard normal distribution respectively. Then the task is to compute$\int x f_{X_{(k)}}(x) \,dx$. Thr approximation of this integral is done [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9010).